# SoapUI escaping < and > to &lt; and &gt;, How to overcome this?

Tags: groovy, soapui

We have a scenario, where the request can send json body and the json body has fields that accepts alphanumeric values
for Ex:

```
{"paramName": "paramValue"}
```

where the param value could be alphanumeric, so the actual request could turn into something like below

```
{"certificationId": "CERT1234<>"}
```

Where as the soapUI is updating those `< and >` chars to `&lt; and &gt;`  chars respectively in the body.
Is there a way to solve this as the QA compares with the same chars in the response?

Comment: napster, have you got chance to try the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the response by replacing those values.

Use groovy script as shown below:

Note that using a fixed response to demonstrate. You can make it to work for dynamic response by using `Script Assertion` instead of `Groovy Script` test step.

```
def response = """{
  "certificationId": "CERT1234&lt;&gt;"
}"""


//map the unescape characters
def map = ['&lt;' : '<', '&gt;' : '>', '&quot;' : '"', '&apos;':'\'', '&amp;':'&']
//Replace them in source string
map.collect {k,v -> response = response.replaceAll(k,v)}

log.info "Response after replacing: $response"
```

You can quickly try it online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/91P1Pd)</kbd>